# Using xslt to put conditions on tags?

Tags: xml, xslt

XSL Newbie

I have a xml file as

```
<parent>
  <child1>The child</child1>
  <child2>
     <subchild1>The subchild 1 </subchild1>
     <subchild2>The subchild 2 </subchild2>
     <ref>1</ref>
  </child2>
  <child3>
  <address> 23 </address>
  <mail> test@test.com </mail>
</child3>
</parent>
```

I want xsl to make the following changes

```
<parent>
  <child1>The child</child>
  <child2>
     <subchild1>The subchild 1 </subchild>
     <subchild2>The subchild 2 </subchild>
     <ref refid = "aff1">1</ref>
  </child2>
  <child3>
  <address> 23 </address>
  <mail type="email"> test@test.com </mail>
</parent>
```

My XSL so far is

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I can iterate over every tag and text but how to put a if statement and make changes.
`aff` will be fixed but the number will get appended.
The way I run this in ubuntu is

`$ xsltproc iterate1.xsl headerout1.xml`

Comment: For `<ref refid = 1>` (which should really be `<ref refid="1" />` to make the XML well-formed), where does the value of the `refid` attribute come from? Will it always be "1"? Will it be the same as the value of the `<ref>` node? Or do you want to be incremented for each occurence of a `<ref>` in the document? Thanks

Comment: It will be same as `ref` element content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started off well by using the identity template. All you need to do now is add templates that match the nodes you want to change. XSLT has the concept of template priority, so if two templates match a given node, the one with the higher priority is used. (A template matching a specific node name like "ref" has a priority of 0, compared with a template matching "node()" which has a priority of -0.5)

So, to transform the `ref` you would do this....

```
<xsl:template match="ref">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or better still, use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates), and do this:

```
<xsl:template match="ref">
    <ref id="{.}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </ref>
</xsl:template>
```

You would do something similar for `mail` (although slightly simpler as the value is not dynamic)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mail">
        <mail type="email">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </mail>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref">
        <ref id="{.}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ref>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:transform>
```